# How to use Blazored.LocalStorage in a Blazor code behind file

Tags: local-storage, blazor

All the examples I can find show how to use it in the razor file like this:

```cs
@page "/"

@inject Blazored.LocalStorage.ILocalStorageService localStorage
```

I would like to move it to a Base file (code behind file) but nothing I try seems to work

I tried :

```cs
  public class SomeClassBase : ComponentBase
  {

    [Inject]
    public blazored.LocalStorage.ILocalStorageService;
```

but this did not work.

Any help from someone who is not going to answer with "Why do you want to do this" would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to do this ? Sorry, this is only a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try something like this:

```
[Inject]
public blazored.LocalStorage.ILocalStorageService localStorage { get; set;}
```

As far as I recall you should use a property rather than a field. Try it.

Comment: Hello,Thanks for the reply. I tried your suggestion but

Comment: I got a red squiggly line under blazored that said "The type or namespace name 'blazored' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?" It suggested changing the word to Blazored with a capital B. That worked! Thank you so very much!

Comment: I did exactly same before i find this page, But problem is localStorage is awlays null, even add services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage(); in startup.cs on blazor server side.